# "Search and destroy" iteration doesn't delete all of the items at once

Tags: javascript

I have this block of code to iterate through array and delete all objects that have property `completed` equal to `true`. When I execute function with this block of code it doesn't delete all of the items. It deletes one, or sometimes half of them, then I need to press the button few times to delete all of them instead just once. Why does that happen and how do I fix it?

```
  var toDoItems = $scope.toDoItems;
  for (var i = 0; i < toDoItems.length; i++)
    if (toDoItems[i].completed === true)
      toDoItems.splice(i, 1)
  ls.set('toDoData', toDoItems)
```

Comment: Start at the end and iterate backwards. That way your list indexes don't change due to the removal of the items.

Comment: You are trying to delete elements from an array  while looping over it. That will change the list indices which are yet to come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing splice do `i--` to reduce the counter since `toDoItems.length` has reduced and `i` should remain same for next item.

```
for (var i = 0; i < toDoItems.length; i++)
{
    if (toDoItems[i].completed === true)
    {
      toDoItems.splice(i, 1)
      i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative that I can think of is that instead of removing the items which are completed you can push the items which are not completed into an empty array:

```
var toDoItems = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.toDoItems.length; i++)
   if ($scope.toDoItems[i].completed !== true)
      toDoItems.push($scope.toDoItems[i]);
ls.set('toDoData', toDoItems)
```

Or, you can use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var toDoItems = $scope.toDoItems.filter(function (item) {
    return item.completed !== true;
});

ls.set('toDoData', toDoItems)
```

Comment: Yeah I agree both are really good solutions, however another answer was the closest solution to my specific problem. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I think builtin filter function is quite cleaner than other solutions whether it is pushing items into new array or decreasing the indices etc.

Comment: I agree its cleaner and probably better, but with other code I had to add only 1 line of code.